# How do i read an integer which can be of any value, except if it's a 0, it's not in the file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I need to read data of volleyball players in C++. I've got a text file with the following data in one line:
Name, team, role, score

Name, team, role are strings which i can read just fine with a ifstream getline. Score is an integer, if the player didn't score anything, it's not in the file instead of being a simple zero.
Basically it looks like this:
If a player has atleast scored:

Gabe Newell, Valve, Whatever, 2

If a player has no score:

Gabe Newell, Valve, Whatever

How do i read this thing? My C++ exercise states that i need to find a way to read it.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to tag this question with the language you're using. You should also provide the relevant snippet of code where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Read your line into a `std::string` and count the commas. If there are 3 commas then the user provided the score. Then put the string into a `std::stringstream` and do the parsing from there.

You can also use [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to find the correct pattern.